# instance on amazon stopped respond on 80 port

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I got one instance t2.small EC2 on Amazon. ubuntu 14.04, apache2, php5, mysql (common things).
In case of avoiding some questions fw about open ports, iptables, apache running service, apache listenings ports and other stuff, here it is some detail status of running services

[image: status of running services]

here it is instance security group inbound rules.
inbound rules

[image: inbound rules]

It behaves rather strange. It does not respond on 80 port from outside 
I've tried to telnet on 80 port from outside without success.

But if I change apache port on (for example) 81, it respond

Comment: Perhaps you have some local proxy/firewall involved? Can you try from another location?

Comment: I've tried from several locations, but the same problem.

Comment: You are trying with public IP address and not with domain name?

Comment: I've tried both ip and dns